# SVN slow on Linux drive

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm developing a PHP project on Eclipse Juno with Subclipse in Windows, the source files are from a mapped drive on Linux. Recently I was forced to change the repository of that project and from then, all the SVN operations are running EXTREMELY slow...I tried the following:

- Test the repository source in three different sites (2 online -CloudForge and Codespaces- and 1 in my LAN). Doesn't work so I suppose it is not a repository speed issue.
- Tried to switch to Tortoise SVN instead of Subclipse...painfully slow again.
- Tried to use Git instead of SVN...a lot of problems again.

So I'm thinking about a drive speed issue...

Any help?

Comment: There are some disadvantatges working on a local copy:
- I am preventing future issues or config problems if I develop on an environment that is very similar to the production environment.
- If I develop in the server everyone can check my progression.
There is any way to create a faster unit drive?

Answer (score 0):

Where you host your repository is definitely not relevant.  The problem is hosting your working copy on a network mounted filesystem.

Try upgrading to Subclipse 1.10.x which uses SVN 1.8.  And then turn on this feature:

http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#exclusivelocking

It might make things fast enough to be tolerable.  The best solution would be to have your working copy on your local hard drive and use rsync or something if you wanted to copy changes to the mapped drive for testing.